# Multiplication Table in javascript and how about to align the row

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiplication

I tried to a do Multiplication Table in JS and I want to print in `<p>` element out (Use DOM and not use `document.write` method).

I tried to use `"&#9;"` or `"\t"` to align column , but when number is double digit (from x3 column) , it got typographic issue.

Does it any ways could solve this problem?

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("printout");
var s = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
    s = s + j + "*" + i + " = " + (i * j) + "&#9;";
  }

  s = s + "<br>";
}

p1.innerHTML = s;
```

```html
<pre id="printout"></pre>
```

Comment: write the values into `span` elements and align them using CSS.

Comment: If you use the snippet editor then please also use the _"Tidy"_ function _before_ posting your question.

Comment: _"I tried to a do Multiplication **Table**"_ - There are cases where a table is the right tool, so why don't you use a `<table>`?

Comment: @Moha the almighty camel - Thanks , but I just tried to use HTML only to solve this issue.

Comment: @ Andreas - Thanks for your advice , I'll try to use Tidy" function next questions .
                      I just tried to use HTML only to solve this issue , not to use other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing table column wise, print row wise.

And wrap your each table in a div, so that aligning them becomes easy.

var p1 = document.getElementById("printout");

```
var s = "";

        for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            
                        s = s + "<div>";

            for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {

                s =  s + i + "*" + j + " = " + (i*j) + "<Br/>" ;
                
            }

            s =  s + "</div>";
            
        }


        p1.innerHTML =  s;
```

Little bit CSS

```
#printout {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#printout div {
  padding:10px;
  min-width:100px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wkg92rud/

Answer (score 0):

Inspiring from @Andreas suggestion, Using `<table>`

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("printout");
var s = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
    let col = document.createElement("td");
    col.innerText = j + "*" + i + " = " + (i * j);
    row.append(col);
  }
  p1.append(row);
}
```

```css
td {
  padding: 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="printout"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dalvik method is the correct way, styling and alignment should be done through CSS.

However, in other environments like command line, or if you are doing this as an exercise to learn JS you can use string padding, here is an example:

```
const p1 = document.getElementById("printout");
const LONGEST_ENTRY = 9; // Longest string you will have is 9 characters long
const entries = []

        for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                const entry = `${j}*${i} = ${(i*j)}`.padEnd(LONGEST_ENTRY, " ") ; // use string interpolation, then pad the string with spaces until the length of LONGEST_ENTRY is reached
                entries.push(entry); // store all the entries in an array
            }
            entries.push("<br/>"); // add a line break at the end of each row
        }
p1.innerHTML =  entries.join(''); // join all the elements
```

Here is a [jsfiddle as an example](https://jsfiddle.net/zw17pxrf/)

Comment: @ Moha the almighty camel - Thanks for your advice , some methods are difficult to me , I'll learn and figure out these methods. Thanks.